# How to verify if method was called with set of specified elements in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have a test in Spock:

```
def repository= Mock(Repository)

@Subject
def service = new Service(repository)

def "test"() {
  given:
  def results = [ /* does not matter */ ]

  def element = XYZ

  when:
  def found = service.findByElement(element)

  then:
  1 * repository.findByElements(_ as Set) >> results 
}
```

which is working properly. But I would like to verify if `repository.findByElements` method is taking one element set with our specific element. How to achieve this?

Neither this:

```
1 * repository.findByElements([element] as Set) >> results
```

nor this:

```
1 * repository.findByElements({ assert it == [element] as Set }) >> results
```

does not work.

Comment: Did you try `1 * repository.findByElements({it == [element] as Set }) >> results` as well? If so, please post the console log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [an argument constraint](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_argument_constraints) that expects a closure representing a predicate. It looks similar to your second use case - the only difference is that there is no `assert` keyword needed (predicate has to return a boolean value). Variable `it` holds the argument value that your mocked method retrieves while being called, so you can create a predicate based on passed value.

```
def repository= Mock(Repository)

@Subject
def service = new Service(repository)

def "test"() {
    given:
    def results = [ /* does not matter */ ]

    def element = new Element("XYZ")

    when:
    def found = service.findByElement(element)

    then:
    1 * repository.findByElements({ it == [element] as Set }) >> results
}
```

Comment: Damn! How could I missed that? Probably not enough caffeine and too many tries ;)